# Block Specific Request URL in chrome, but URL with sub-directory should pass

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, http, https

I am trying to block specific request URL like this -
https://somedomain.co.in/api/consultation

by using **"Block Request URL"** in **Google Chrome Network tab**.

But the issue I am facing is that the Block request URL is blocking all URL starting with the above pattern, like it is blocking -

https://somedomain.co.in/api/consultation/subdirectory

I want to block only - https://somedomain.co.in/api/consultation

I tried Changing the text pattern in **"Network request blocking"** tab, but no luck.

Did anyone face a similar situation?

Note - I don't want to use any extra script, there should be some way with chrome itself or Mozilla or maybe upcoming update in chrome.

Comment: Does that accept regex? In my version (86.0.4240.111) it says "; use * for wildcard" which doesn't sound like it means the Kleene star.

Comment: It probably uses these patterns: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/match_patterns/

Comment: Not able to find any solution yet :(

Comment: Do you wish to block it in the front-end or back-end? If you wish to block it in the back-end, which programming language are you working with? Java, Javascript, .NET, PHP?

Comment: In front end, from browser itself @justthink

Comment: @AyushSharma Are you using some js frontend framework, or want to redirect using vanilla js?

Comment: @AyushSharma what is the condition you have write or what is the regular expression you  have written. Will add piece of code  in your description? Hence I would try to give solutions.

Comment: @Dipak I am asking is there any way we can do this in chrome dev tools, I myself can write regular expression and run the script, I have made some edit in the question, so that people will not get confuse

Comment: @AyushSharma chromedev tool means in inspect element right?

Comment: @AyushSharma What is meaning of  blocking url in chrome dev tool. Chrome dev tool is viewer and it helps to diagnosed the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of the `Developer tools` I can conclude there is no way to do that.

```
/**
 * @param {string} pattern
 * @param {string} url
 * @return {boolean}
 */
_matches(pattern, url) {
    var pos = 0;
    var parts = pattern.split('*');
    for (var index = 0; index < parts.length; index++) {
      var part = parts[index];
      if (!part.length)
        continue;
      pos = url.indexOf(part, pos);
      if (pos === -1)
        return false;
      pos += part.length;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It only supports wildcards using *asterisks*. No matter what you want to ignore with your given URL, it will always match.

There is no support for `RegEx` either, until something like that will be added, it will be possible.

And no, this won't be added anytime soon, unless someone adds this feature and submits a pull request.

https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend